# Chromium `debugger` equivalent, on `gdb` for Cygwin?

Tags: c++, c, gdb, cygwin

How do people trigger a breakpoint on `gdb` (for Cygwin, specifically) from the very source code?

Like when a JS script has the `debugger` word in it and Chromium dev tools trigger stop for debugging?

Comment: remember, when compiling/linking that the necessary information for debugging needs to be kept so the information will be available to the debugger,  when using `gcc`, that information can be saved via the option: `-ggdb3`.  Note other compilers  use different options to have the max debug info available to the debugger.  Note the option used may be different depending on which debugger is to be used.

Comment: [I'm using `-g` to no hassle. Why should, or should not, and for which compilers, on which platforms, switch to `-ggdb3`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61813929/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how SDL2 [implements](https://github.com/spurious/SDL-mirror/blob/master/include/SDL_assert.h#L50) this feature:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
/* Don't include intrin.h here because it contains C++ code */
    extern void __cdecl __debugbreak(void);
    #define SDL_TriggerBreakpoint() __debugbreak()
#elif ( (!defined(__NACL__)) && ((defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)) && (defined(__i386__) || defined(__x86_64__))) )
    #define SDL_TriggerBreakpoint() __asm__ __volatile__ ( "int $3\n\t" )
#elif defined(__386__) && defined(__WATCOMC__)
    #define SDL_TriggerBreakpoint() { _asm { int 0x03 } }
#elif defined(HAVE_SIGNAL_H) && !defined(__WATCOMC__)
    #include <signal.h>
    #define SDL_TriggerBreakpoint() raise(SIGTRAP)
#else
    /* How do we trigger breakpoints on this platform? */
    #define SDL_TriggerBreakpoint()
#endif
```

The conditionals should probably resolve to `__asm__ __volatile__ ( "int $3\n\t" )` on Cygwin.

Comment: Yes! `#include <signal.h>\n[...] raise(SIGTRAP);` saves my day.

Comment: And I don't really get why now, but yes `__asm__ __volatile__ ("int $3\n\t");` effectively saves it definitely even better.

Comment: [On `__asm__ __volatile__`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26456845) and [on `"int $3\n\t"` (I guess)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22379105/1737973)