# What is `int 3` really supposed to do?

Tags: kernel

According [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22380711/1737973) `int 3` is used from userspace to generate SIGTRAP.

But what is that supposed to do from privileged under userspace?

Are there more stuff that can generate such from userspace SIGTRAP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The opcode *int 3* knows nothing of unix conventions, such as SIGTRAP.  Int 3 generates an exception, which is vectored through index 3.  It is conventionally considered a debug exception, and in fact the debug registers will also generate exceptions through the same index.

Int 3 is a bit special because it is a single byte opcode; unlike the other int $n instructions which require 2.   Because it is a single byte, it can be used to place breakpoints in programs by rewriting an existing opcode's first byte with it.
While technically you could use a multi-byte opcode for doing this, it is possible that the next byte in the program text is an important piece of data or a jump label which you might corrupt.

By convention, unix derived OSes will raise a signal (SIGTRAP) when this opcode is encountered; that provides the opportunity for a debugger (or a debug module in the kernel) to look up the offending address to see if it had previously set a breakpoint (or watchpoint) at this address.   If so, it would do the usual debugger stuff.   If not, it would likely propagate the SIGTRAP to the offending process.

In the case where the breakpoint was encountered in privileged (kernel) code, the processing is not much different, but there would be an expectation that a kernel debugger was active, and it would follow similar processing as above, except that the result of no pending breakpoint would probably to halt the system with a bunch of funny numbers on the console.

Comment: _So it is still a_ hack _at the kernel level_? `Int 3 generates an exception, which is vectored through index 3.` <- But assembly knows no exceptions, does it? Did you mean an interruption? If so, which one on ia32 and amd64? And what about other architectures?

Comment: The machine architecture defines the exceptions; so while *assembly* doesn't know them, the machine that implements it knows them quite well.  It isn't really a hack, it is a well defined architectural component, and implemented precisely to fit its purpose.   Its use is broader than debugging, for example many tracing tools rely on breakpoints to detect what has and hasn't been executed.

Comment: A machine exception is not to be confused with a C++ exception. That are different things.