# What's the purpose of many int3's in a row in WinDbg disassembly of ntdll code?

Tags: windows, assembly, visual-c++, disassembly, memory-alignment

I'm learning assembly and after assembly of:

```
format PE64 NX GUI 6.0
entry start

section '.text' code readable executable
start:
        int3
        ret
```

running in my debugger (at the end of the OS loader code and also ) I see

```
...
00007fff`bc78070d 4889442428         mov     qword ptr [rsp+28h], rax
00007fff`bc780712 488364242000       and     qword ptr [rsp+20h], 0
00007fff`bc780718 e8cf90f9ff         call    ntdll!RtlStringCbPrintfExW (00007fff`bc7197ec)
00007fff`bc78071d 488b8c24e0010000   mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsp+1E0h]
00007fff`bc780725 4833cc             xor     rcx, rsp
00007fff`bc780728 e813bbfbff         call    ntdll!_security_check_cookie (00007fff`bc73c240)
00007fff`bc78072d 4881c4f0010000     add     rsp, 1F0h
00007fff`bc780734 5b                 pop     rbx
00007fff`bc780735 c3                 ret     
00007fff`bc780736 cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc780737 cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc780738 cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc780739 cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc78073a cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc78073b cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc78073c cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc78073d cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc78073e cc                 int     3
00007fff`bc78073f cc                 int     3
    ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak:
00007fff`bc780740 4883ec38           sub     rsp, 38h
00007fff`bc780744 488364242000       and     qword ptr [rsp+20h], 0
00007fff`bc78074a 41b901000000       mov     r9d, 1
00007fff`bc780750 4c8d442440         lea     r8, [rsp+40h]
00007fff`bc780755 418d5110           lea     edx, [r9+10h]
00007fff`bc780759 48c7c1feffffff     mov     rcx, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEh
00007fff`bc780760 e84bcbfcff         call    ntdll!NtQueryInformationThread (00007fff`bc74d2b0)
00007fff`bc780765 85c0               test    eax, eax
00007fff`bc780767 780a               js      ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x33 (00007fff`bc780773)
00007fff`bc780769 807c244000         cmp     byte ptr [rsp+40h], 0
00007fff`bc78076e 7503               jne     ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x33 (00007fff`bc780773)
00007fff`bc780770 cc                 int     3
...
```

Can someone explain what the purpose of multiple `int3`'s in a row? It reminds me of a `nop` slide but I can't imagine why you'd need to do such a thing with a debug command. Or is this just bad disassembly?

Comment: MS compiles their DLLs with MSVC, which uses `int3` for alignment padding.  Many other compilers use `nop` for that purpose.

Comment: aside from padding, executing int 3 is how software breakpoint implemented. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61816297/what-is-int-3-really-supposed-to-do